# Proper way to Abort (stop) running async/await function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, cancellation

There has been other topics on SE, but most of them are dated 5 years ago. What is the current, up-to-date approach to cancel await call in JS?  i.e.

```
async myFunc(){
    let response = await oneHourLastingFunction();
    myProcessData(response);
}
```

at specific moment application decides it no longer want to wait that `oneHourLastingFunction`, but it is stuck in "await". How to cancel that? Any standard ways of cancelation-tokens/[abortControllers](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/canceling-javascript-async-tasks-with-abortcontroller-acda9f67f7e7) for promises?

Comment: "*What is the current, up-to-date approach to cancel await call in JS?*" other than being impossible? There hasn't been any new developments there. Unless you specifically make your own function cancellable, that is.

Comment: An answer saying "the old questions you found are still up to date"? Sounds like a duplicate to me.

Comment: @VLAZ and what about AbortControllers? https://javascript.plainenglish.io/canceling-javascript-async-tasks-with-abortcontroller-acda9f67f7e7

Comment: @vlaz if there is no update in last 6 years, what a pity. you can mark topic as duplicate.

Comment: You can use `Promise.race([oneHourLastingFunction(), delay(time)])`, However it doesn't  
 cancel other operation... So you should use `AbortControllers`, Most API support this...

Comment: The general mechanism is you throw an exception. `AbortController` is a standardized mechanism for this. It's opt-in. You can't arbitrarily cancel any async operation.

Comment: Geez this thread is a sad indictment of the state of JavaScript. How can web interfaces not be built to be interruptable as a first class language construct?

Answer (score 6):

Canceling an asynchronous procedure is still not a trivial task, especially when you need deep cancellation and flow control. There is no native solution at the moment. All you can do natively:

- pass AbortController instance to each nested async function you want to make cancellable
- subscribe all internal micro-tasks (requests, timers, etc) to the signal
- optionally unsubscribe completed micro-tasks from the signal
- call `abort` method of the controller to cancel all subscribed micro-tasks

This is quite verbose and a tricky solution with potential memory leaks.

I can just suggest my own solution to this challenge- [c-promise2](https://github.com/DigitalBrainJS/c-promise), which provides cancelable promises and a cancelable alternative for ECMA asynchronous functions - generators.

Here is an basic example ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-timeout-cancellation-c31qm?file=/src/index.js)):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

// deeply cancelable generator-based asynchronous function
const oneHourLastingFunction = CPromise.promisify(function* () {
  // optionally just for logging
  this.onCancel(() =>
    console.log("oneHourLastingFunction::Cancel signal received")
  );
  yield CPromise.delay(5000); // this task will be cancelled on external timeout
  return "myData";
});

async function nativeAsyncFn() {
  await CPromise.delay(5000);
}

async function myFunc() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await oneHourLastingFunction().timeout(2000);
  } catch (err) {
    if (!CPromise.isCanceledError(err)) throw err;
    console.warn("oneHourLastingFunction::timeout", err.code); // 'E_REASON_TIMEOUT'
  }
  await nativeAsyncFn(response);
}

const nativePromise = myFunc();
```

Deeply cancellable solution (all functions are cancellable) ([Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cpromise-timeout-deep-cancellation-jo2l2)):

```
import { CPromise } from "c-promise2";

// deeply cancelable generator-based asynchronous function
const oneHourLastingFunction = CPromise.promisify(function* () {
  yield CPromise.delay(5000);
  return "myData";
});

const otherAsyncFn = CPromise.promisify(function* () {
  yield CPromise.delay(5000);
});

const myFunc = CPromise.promisify(function* () {
  let response;
  try {
    response = yield oneHourLastingFunction().timeout(2000);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code !== "E_REASON_TIMEOUT") throw err;
    console.log("oneHourLastingFunction::timeout");
  }
  yield otherAsyncFn(response);
});

const cancellablePromise = myFunc().then(
  (result) => console.log(`Done: ${result}`),
  (err) => console.warn(`Failed: ${err}`)
);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("send external cancel signal");
  cancellablePromise.cancel();
}, 4000);
```